# SQLite3で、insertしたカラム（のIDまたはROWID）を取得するには？

Tags: sql, sqlite

たとえば、SQL Serverの場合だと次のような方法があります。

```
CREATE TABLE TABLENAME(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,colmn1 nvarchar(10),colmn2 nvarchar(10));
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO TABLENAME(colmn1,colmn2) VALUES(DATA1,DATA2);
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'ident' // ここでIDを取得可能
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

現在、SQLite3では、よくないなと感じながらも、方法の一つとして、次のように取得しています。

```
create table test(id integer primary key,test text);
BEGIN;
insert into test(test) values("Fooooooooooooooo");
select max(id) from test;
1
COMMIT;
```

本来、SQLite3では新規レコードのIDを取得するには、どのように取得することが正しいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

恐らくですが、

```
select last_insert_rowid();
```

でよいことがわかりました。
お騒がせいたしました。

これ以外に良い回答がございましたらお教えいただければ幸いです。

Comment: 解決済みにするには、48時間の経過が必要になるそうで、現在質問を閉じることができません。申し訳ありません。